# Can't make CSS changes to my page elements, am I referencing them wrong?

Tags: html, css

Trying to add a hide feature to an image based on screen size to be replaced by a modified version of the image to be hidden until page width crosses over to mobile. My result has been both images appearing on the site no matter the page width.

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-wrapper center text-center">
            <div class="cell">
                <h2 class="black">A vs B</h2>
                <div class="desktop-mg-rls"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1173/4268/files/OB-MG--Chart-2.jpg?v=1624026013" class="compare" /></div>
                <div class="mobile-mg-rls"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1173/4268/files/OB_MG_Mobile_RLS_Chart.jpg?v=1624034078" class="compare" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
.desktop-mg-rls.compare {display: block;}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .desktop-mg-rls.compare {display: none;}
}

.mobile-mg-rls.compare {display: none;}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .mobile-mg-rls.comapre {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. You need a space in `.desktop-mg-rls.compare`. It should be `.desktop-mg-rls .compare `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are referencing them wrong. When you use a selector like `.desktop-mg-rls.compare`, you are selecting a `.desktop-mg-rls` that **also has the "compare" class**. If you want to select **children with the "compare" class**, you need to insert a space between `.desktop-mg-rls` and `.compare`. Moreover, there is a typo in `.mobile-mg-rls.comapre`. Hence, the code should be this way:

```css
.desktop-mg-rls .compare {display: block;}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .desktop-mg-rls .compare {display: none;}
}

.mobile-mg-rls .compare {display: none;}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .mobile-mg-rls .compare {display: block;}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="page-wrapper center text-center">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <h2 class="black">A vs B</h2>
                        <div class="desktop-mg-rls"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1173/4268/files/OB-MG--Chart-2.jpg?v=1624026013" class="compare" /></div>
                        <div class="mobile-mg-rls"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1173/4268/files/OB_MG_Mobile_RLS_Chart.jpg?v=1624034078" class="compare" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>        
    </body>
</html>
```

However, there is a better way to do what you are trying to. To know more, read about [HTML picture Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply, I made the changes to the typo and spacing but still get both images displaying independent of the screen size?

Comment: Are you sure? If you run the snippet above, you can see the code working. Compare your code with the code in the snippet.

Comment: The Picture tag link syntax worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why this page isn't responding the same as code snippet running. But being able to make the change inline will work to avoid whatever is happening between this page and the css file.